# Yum is not getting installed

Tags: yum

I was trying to install yum on my **ubuntu 14.04** and to use **libcgroup** in fedora, to install the required packages I used

```
$ sudo yum install libcgroup libcgroup-tools
```

It throws an error

> There are no enabled repos.
>    Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
>    You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable 
>   test@test-desktop:~$ yum repolist all
>   repolist: 0

Anyone has any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following repositories.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

To enable all ubuntu software (`main universe restricted multiverse`) repositories use

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
```

you can add also `partner` repository with different link (see difference is ubuntu to canonical)

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

Then update the package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then 
`sudo apt-get install pakagename` like

```
sudo apt-get install libcgroup
```

p.s.

for all differences in repositories read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks Abdul,
It tried whatever u suggested and when I try to run the last sudo apt-get install libcgroup command it gives an error: Unable to locate package libcgroup

Comment: check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt